# Arduino Micro + Max4466 - Noise on A0

Tags: analogread, arduino-micro, analog-sampling

I've got an Arduino Micro, and a MAX4466 ECM / AMP breakout board (https://www.adafruit.com/product/1063). I'm powering the Arduino Micro from the USB port.

On the MAX4466 (to the Arduino), I've wired VCC to 3.3v, GND to GND, and OUT to A0. I've also wired 3.3v to AREF.

Using the following code, I'm noticing significant noise spikes on the output, as shown in the graph below.

I'm not entirely sure what I've done wrong here, and would appreciate any input / criticism that could lead to getting a clean signal.

```cpp
void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
   analogReference(EXTERNAL);
}


void loop()
{
   Serial.println(analogRead(0));
}
```

[image]

Comment: And if you sample at exactly 50Hz or a multiple thereof?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've just taken another sample, both with the above code, and with the above code, with addition of a call to delay by 20ms per sample. This screenshot shows the result: http://s21.postimg.org/4fplz8g8n/Screenshot_from_2015_06_27_06_00_54.png. As you can see, the noise is much lower now, and I'm not seeing such massive peaks any more..although there are still some peaks, at a much lower amplitude.

Comment: You could average the samples to get a lower noise. But it kind of depends on what you are trying to achieve. As you notice the noise only produces values lower than expected, not higher. So if you want to e.g. detect a clap, this kind of noise doesn't really affect your program, as you'd measure peaks. (PS try increasing the baudrate of the serial connection and see what that does.)

Comment: You could try adding a resistor between 3.3v and AREF or even better an inductor.

Comment: @Gerben thanks for the comments. I've actually got a sketch with 4 frame averaging ready, just haven't had a minute to test it yet :) RE the resistor, I've read the same about between A0 and GND. I'll see if I can pick up a few different resistors later and give them a try :) Will report back

Comment: Try this: Aim is to isolate mic module from any Arduino or supply noise. | Measure module current with a milliammeter. [**Data sheet here for 4466**](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/MAX4465-MAX4469.pdf) - likey current uncertain but seems likely to be < 1 mA. Maybe not. Add a series R that drops about 0.3V (Vcc min = 2.4V) R max = 0.3V/mA_drawn. eg if I = 1 mA the Rn=max = 0.3/.001 = 300 Ohms - > use 270 Ohms or less. Add a largish capacitor at module from Vcc to ground and feed Vcc via Ras above. C = 100 uF probably OK. Higher does not hurt.

Comment: Thanks @RussellMcMahon for your input. I wasn't able to get anything from my local Maplins as they were closed, but I'll drop in either tomorrow or Monday. I'll also update this question with a photo of my (surely dreadful) layout. I don't have a millammeter available to me, but I'll see if I can acquire one. This was meant to be a simple little audio recorder experiment, so if the cost of the equipment is going to be relatively high, I'm not sure I can warrant it right now..we'll see. I'll be back!

Comment: @Seidr   "milliammeter" can be almost any modern DMM (digital multi-meter) -  essentially any of these can measure up to 200 mA and cost can be modest and they are utterly invaluable when doing anything with electronics. | Aim overall is to feed clean power to module and to get clean signal back. Ground paths should be direct and if a number of things are powered use "star" grounds - all grounds radiate from a single point - no loops formed.

Comment: Pulled out my ollllld multi meter, and it's reading a current of 2mA. I'll try going shopping for parts again tomorrow. Thanks :)

Comment: My thanks for all your input. I believe I've discovered the cause of the noise - the serial port. The higher the baud rate goes, the higher the frequency of the noise. I've also tried the same setup on a friends Arduino Uno, and could not detect any noise. I'm going to try this with a stand alone power supply tomorrow, and see if that resolves the noise issues or not. Using a small capacitor to ground did help slightly also :)

Comment: Ok - so I suspected that it was the Arduino at fault.. Turns out it's a cheap Chinese clone. After purchasing an official Micro, and wiring up the same component, I'm getting a nice clean signal (bar a small amount of acceptable noise), which is reflecting input tones accurately. Thanks again for all the input!

Comment: I copy-paste your last comment as an answer. Please, accept it to close your question.

Answer (score 1):

The OP itself solve it:

> Ok - so I suspected that it was the Arduino at fault.. Turns out it's
>   a cheap Chinese clone. After purchasing an official Micro, and wiring
>   up the same component, I'm getting a nice clean signal (bar a small
>   amount of acceptable noise), which is reflecting input tones
>   accurately. Thanks again for all the input!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting plot. Gives me the impression that your reference is sagging, consider adding some local storage (tant/ceramic capacitors) across the cpu's power in pins and across the cpu's Reference pin. Would also be interesting to know if adding more delay between measurements would improve performance. Thanks for sharing you issue.